# Difficulty syncing ipad app from iTunes using ad-hoc provisioning

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios6

I have written an app and distributed it by emailing the .mobileprovision and the .ipa  to my testers a number of times without any problems at all. However the last time I have done this I am told by one that it will not sync. It loads into iTunes well enough but just will not sync. Same iPads, all included in the profile.

I am using XCode version 4.6 (4H127) and the ipad has recently been updated to 6.1.3. Can anyone confirm whether I should be able to distribute this way or whether my version of XCode and the ipad are no longer compatible.

Comment: You should use TestFlight. This is not an answer, but hopefully its helpful. I find TF is quite useful and usually works better than anything else.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=testflight&aq=f&oq=testflight&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l4j0.3078j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Resend the .mobileprovision file and the .ipa and re-sync.  I had this problem with one of my testers as well, and they had to go through removing the app from iTunes, re-add the .mobileprovision and .ipa back.  This worked just fine.